# How to help a beginner to speak German?

Tags: learning, speaking

I am a German native speaker and I am going to help a student with speaking German, who is at beginner level.

**How would we have the conversation such that the student can take the most out of it?**

Obvious points I made up so far:

- Speak slowly.
- Speak clearly.
- Make short sentences, avoid complicated nested structures.

What are common mistakes at beginner level I should watch out for? Is it necessary to correct the student when they make errors concerning

- articles,
- plural forms,
- tense forms,
- sentence structures,

if the meaning of the sentence comes across?

I don't have any educational background for teaching German. In this specific case, the native language of the student is English.

I have asked a similar question [in the Stack Exchange for Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-to-help-a-beginner-with-speaking)

Comment: Are you the only teacher? What is the native language of your student?

Comment: No I am not the only teacher but I don't have the contact of their real teacher. The native language of the student is English.

Comment: Für den nicht sprachspezifischen Teil ist vielleicht auch https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/ hilfreich.

Comment: @CarstenS Danke für den Hinweis!

Comment: Bitte ergänze in deiner Frage noch den muttersprachlichen Hintergrund des Schülers bzw. der Schülerin! Danke :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as we teach our children our language.

Correct short to medium length sentences, always one level above their current level.
Be strict what you say, be forgiving at their errors.

From time to time do a short lesson in grammar theory, but don't be a correcting teacher all the time.

The rest will come as time goes by.

Comment: Thanks, keeping in mind to be one level above their current level feels quite helpful to me

Comment: Just don't fall into the habit of talking 'baby' or 'foreigner' language.

Answer (score 2):

Make them understand German does not follow the English S-P-O word order. Most learning materials stick to that prerequisite much too long for the sake of building German sentences that look like English sentences. In result, many English speakers get the wrong impression German is just English with different words.

German word order in general is S-O-P. It's only the main clause that has another complication, the V2 verb. That one is put **in front of the subject**, and **the item in front of the V2 verb isn't the subject but the topic.**

German tells apart pronoun and noun accusative objects in terms of word order, and the adverbials that do not modify the predicate directly are in front of the noun accusative object rather than at the end.

Also, German handles tenses much different from English. It only ever tells apart non-past and past. There are no continous nor imperfect aspects in German, and neither there are tense relations required by grammar. All past ist perfect, and Perfekt is the preferred tense for talking about the past. Präteritum (not "Imperfekt"!) is for stories. Those may play in the past, but that's an arbitrary decision of the storyteller.

Compare

> Gestern **habe** ich *die ganze Zeit* Gitarre **gespielt**.

> Yesterday, I **played** the guitar *all day*.

Comment: German word order in general is S-O-P. Really?

Comment: Yeah, sure. All the predicate stuff is always at the end. Only the finite verb ever moves to the V2 position in main clauses. And sometimes not even entirely, but the separable prefix sticks to the end, where the finite verb would be in a dependent clause.

Comment: SOP is as wrong as SPO. The finite verb comes second for main clauses: *Gestern **habe** ich die ganze Zeit Gitarre gespielt.* *Gestern **hast** du die ganze Zeit Gitarre gespielt.* And last for subordinate clausus: *, weil ich gestern ... gespielt **habe**.*

Comment: You don't understand the meaning of *in general* then. It means *always but for the following exceptions*. Which I listed right after that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Bezüglich Grammatik:
Je nach Muttersprache der lernenden Person ist es sinnvoll, klare Parallelen zwischen der Grammatik in der Muttersprache und Deutsch aufzuzeigen.
Bringe der lernenden Person eine Zeitform nach der anderen bei. Beginne mit dem Präsens. Deutsch ist sehr formelhaft und es ist deshalb hilfreich, die deutschen Satzstrukturen klar aufzuzeigen und auswendig zu lernen.

Nach meiner Erfahrung ist ein grammatischer Grundstein im Präsens hilfreich, aber nicht der Hauptfaktor zum erfolgreichen Lernen am Anfang. Deshalb empfehle ich auf folgenden Punkte zu achten:

**Stärke das Selbstvertrauen:**
Aller Anfang ist schwer. Bringe deinem/deiner Schüler/in einige nützliche Sätze bei, die im Alltag eingesetzt werden können. Als Lernender einige Sätze zu verstehen und darauf eine vorbereitete Antwort zu haben, verleiht ein Gefühl von Sprachverständnis.

**Passe dein Sprachniveau an:**
Kenne das verfügbare Vokabular deines Gegenübers. Du möchtest, wenn möglich, nicht zu viele neue Wörter auf einmal verwenden. Es ist sehr einfach, einer lernenden Person das Gefühl zu vermitteln, dass er/sie nichts versteht.

**Kenne deine Schüler/innen und deren sprachlichen Hintergrund:**
Falls die lernende Person bereits eine Sprache spricht, die Lehnwörter aus dem Deutschen hat, dann nutze dies.
Zum Beispiel ist das Wort Kindergarten im Englischen dasselbe wie auf Deutsch.

**Nutze historische und etymologisch Fakten, um ein besseres Sprachverständnis zu verleihen:**
Manche Personen lernen besser, wenn Sie neue Informationen mit interessanten oder bereits gelernten Fakten verbinden können. Zum Beispiel, [die Geschichte, die erklärt, warum im Englischen die Tiernamen nicht mit dem Namen des entsprechenden Fleischs übereinstimmen](https://www.dictionary.com/e/animal-names-change-become-food/), kann manchen Personen helfen die relevanten Wörter zu verinnerlichen.

**Nutze Musik, Kunst und persönliche Interessen, um den Lernprozess zu unterstützen:**
Finde deutsche Musik, Bücher, Filme und Serien, die der lernenden Person gefallen. Zum Beispiel halfen mir persönlich Lieder wie "Je ne regrette rien" von Édith Piaf oder "Sur le Pont d'Avignon", Französisch zu lernen.

**Perfektion kann warten**
Wähle deine Kritik gezielt. Korrigiere die Fehler, die relevant sind in Bezug auf das Lernniveau der lernenden Person. Wähle den Zeitpunkt für Kritik sorgfältig und sprich dich mit der lernenden Person ab, wann und wie er/sie Kritik am besten aufnimmt.

Comment: *epidemiologisch* ?? - meintest du vielleicht *enzyklopädisch*? Bitte prüfe bei der Gelegenheit auch hier und da noch mal die Rechtschreibung! Danke :)

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich meinte etymologisch

Comment: ich habe eigentlich nur Kommas und Groß-/Kleinschreibung bearbeiten wollen, kam aber um zwei kleinere Umformulierungen nicht herum. *Fleisches* habe ich in *Fleischs* geändert, beides geht, aber die Form mit dem *e* wird für das Fleisch, das man isst, sehr selten verwendet. Ich hoffe alles in deinem Sinne.

Comment: Sinn kann man nicht machen - es tut mir so leid, aber ich musste das sagen :(

Comment: @choXer vielen Dank fuer den Hinweis.

Comment: @avgJoe etwas hat Sinn, ist sinnvoll oder ergibt Sinn. https://germanblogs.de/sinn-machen-oder-sinn-ergeben-so-heisst-es-richtig/ (Man hört "Sinn machen" aber sehr (!) oft.

Comment: @choXer, Sprache entwickelt sich, ob es Puristen gefällt, oder nicht.

Comment: @infinitezero hast du mich gerade liebevoll einen Idioten genannt? ;) :*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

**Use body language.**

For example: point at things you're talking about, count with fingers, gesture while talking to give them a visual idea about the content.